# Delete button that actually deletes record from tables in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, button

Im very new to Access, so theres a lot i dont know. 
I've currently got a form that has a combo box, some text boxes, and a delete button on it.
I've managed to get the textboxes to autofill based on what the user selects from the combo box, but im stuck with how to go about deleting that record.

At current, my delete button was set up through Button wizard, and when pressed, only deletes the record from the textboxes on the form (clearing the form). What i want it to do is actually delete that entire record from the table that the form is based upon. I just have no idea of what the code i should put behind the button is.

Sorry if that makes no sense. Basically, all i want is a button that when pressed, deletes the record that the user has selected from the combo box, from the table that the record came from.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

The button wizard will give you a working delete button, however this deletes the current record, so you should ensure that your combo box changes the current record.

Note that if you are coding your own delete button you should use `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord` instead of the `DoCmd.DoMenuItem` calls that the wizard generates.

Comment: The button wizard only gives me a button that "clears" the form so to say. I would like a button that actually deletes that record from the database, i just dont know what the code is. Thank you for your answer though!

Comment: @Hoops Is the form actually connected to a table?

Comment: @Hoops Does the button warn you that you are about to delete a record (assuming you have those warnings turned on; you would see that warning if you tried to use the menu to delete the record)?

Comment: No. I just re-tested the Wizard generated Delete button, and all it does is clear the textboxes on the form, and not delete the record from the table the form is based upon. No warnings or anything come up.

Comment: I think im just going to create a DeleteQuery and then run that through a Macro which is initiated when the button is clicked.

Comment: @Hoops It sounds very likely that there is something odd about your set-up. It is nearly always better to solve a problem than to work around it. A delete button will normally give a message.